# How to upgrade the WebForm module?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm planning on upgrading the [WebForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module in my Drupal 7 site. The current WebForm version is 7.x-3.19 and I'm upgrading to 7.x-4.2.

Question: Is it as simple as uploading the new version? Do I need to run `update.php` afterwards?

Somehow I seem to remember that updating the WebForm module is not as simple as other modules and can cause existing webforms to break.

Comment: No guarantees of course, but I must have run the same update on 2-dozen sites and more; no problems so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine with the upgrade.  Back up your DB, of course.  If you are uploading the module instead of installing through the UI, then yes, you need to run /update.php.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I always backup..learned that lesson the hard way.

Comment: Also, read through this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/1609324

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if it was helpful ;-)

Comment: One final thing, if I install via the UI, I don't need to run update.php?

Comment: How do I mark as answered?

Comment: The check mark.